# Can I recover my previous media after factory reset?

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, format

I forgot my admin password and instead of resetting the password I actually clicked *factory reset*.

I lost all my pictures and videos or you can say all media - everything. I have no other backup.

Is there any way to recover them?

Comment: Can you give us more details?  What OS are you using?

Comment: And in general, unless you do backups, you can't usually recover stuff like that.

Comment: Factory reset on Ubuntu? never heard before.

Answer (score 3):

### No.

You've just wiped out everything. Permanently.

Sorry mate.